# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPl atform

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, null

We are trying to upgrade our flutter project to null safety migration using the following link https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide.

dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety - Successful dart pub get - Successful Migrate your code by hand- https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migrating-by-hand - Successful dart migrate - Successful

Facing below error while trying to run the flutter command(Flutter run)

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(28223): com.moltonbrown.fragrancefinder requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(28223): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore(28223): (24.4.3) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
E/flutter (28223): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPl
atform
E/flutter (28223): #0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_i
nterface_document_snapshot.dart:87:7)
E/flutter (28223): #1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_inter
face_document_snapshot.dart:105:23)
E/flutter (28223): #2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_s
napshot.dart:121:12)
E/flutter (28223): #3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
E/flutter (28223): #4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
```

Code snippet which is throwing error:

```
dynamic _findKeyValueInMap(String key, Map<String, dynamic> map) {
      if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        return map[key];
      }

      throw StateError(
        'field does not exist within the $DocumentSnapshotPlatform',
      );
    }
```

dynamic value = _findKeyValueInMap(components[componentIndex], data!);

Comment: Can you provide a minimum recreatable example ?  

If it was working before the attempt to migrate to null safety, there shouldn't be an issue with build.gradle. If this wasn't working before the attempt, you might also try adding implementation `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'` in your build.gradle, or try an emulator that has play services installed.

I highly doubt though that it has something to do with configuration, since you mentioned that it started popping up after the attempt to migrate to null safety.